# Content/ Site share on Blogger and Tumblr

Tags: php, wordpress, share, tumblr, blogger

Can any body tell me how to share Url or content of a site by PHP on Blogger and Tumblr as how we can share on Facebook with

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=sitename/pagabc" target="blank"><img src="images/fbshare.png" /></a>
```

or Twitter

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=TestText&url=sitename/pagabc" target="_blank"><img src="images/twittershare.png" /></a>
```

Comment: blogger does not support php

Comment: Hei Michel . Yes are somehow right and somehow not. Because Blogger share can be done by the following way `http://blogger.com/blog-this.g?t=&u=[PHP ECHO URL]&n=[PHP Title]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following and I hope your problem will be solved.

For Tumblr

```
http://tumblr.com/share?s=&v=3&t=[Share Name Title/PHP ECHO Share Name Title]&u=[URL/PHP ECHO URL]
```

For Blogger

```
http://blogger.com/blog-this.g?t=[TEXT]&n=[Share Name Title/PHP ECHO Share Name Title]&u=[URL/PHP ECHO URL]
```

Comment: Great, it worked for me to. NOTICE: I was trying it from localhost because it is there were I am developing the website and it didn't work, causing a bit frustration for a while. But It does work when the website is in public. Thank you again